# How GIS and SDI (spatial data infrastructure) are related?

Tags: data

I read the definitions of both on wikipedia but they didn't mention any relationship between the two terms although there must be one because they are dealing with the same thing: spatial data. 
Can we consider that regional GISs are building blocks of a national SDI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I see it is Spatial Data Infrasture is the whole network and framework of geospatial data. It involves everything from standards to data to databases to software. **A desktop or web GIS can be a part of a SDI** but it is not the entire SDI. All parts are required for the use and analysis of spatial data, as expressed in the following  quotations:

ESRI:

> The term spatial data infrastructure was coined in 1993 by the U.S.
>   National Research Council to denote a framework of technologies,
>   policies, and institutional arrangements that together facilitate the
>   creation, exchange, and use of geospatial data and related information
>   resources across an information-sharing community. Such a framework
>   can be implemented narrowly to enable the sharing of geospatial
>   information within an organization or more broadly for use at a
>   national, regional, or global level. In all cases, an SDI will provide
>   an institutionally sanctioned, automated means for posting,
>   discovering, evaluating, and exchanging geospatial information by
>   participating information producers and users.

The document which this is quoted from also gives a good indication on the different of a GIS and a SDI. See: http://www.gdmc.nl/publications/2001/Spatial_data_infrasructure.pdf

Steiniger and Hunter (2012) distinguish the following five components:

> (i) Spatial Data (or spatial information), (ii) Technologies, i.e.
>   hardware and software, (iii) Laws and Policies, (iv) People, i.e.:
>   data providers, service providers, users, and (v) Standards for data
>   acquisition, representation and transfer.

and Kuhn (2005) gives this deffintion:

> "An SDI is a coordinated series of agreements on technology standards,
>   institutional arrangements, and policies that enable the discovery and
>   use of geospatial information by users and for purposes other than
>   those it was created for."

**Sources:**

Kuhn W (2005) Introduction to Spatial Data Infrastructures. Presentation held on March 14
2005. Available from: http://www.docstoc.com/docs/2697206/Introduction-to-Spatial--Data-
Infrastructures

Steiniger, S. and Hunter, A.J.S. , 2012. Free and Open Source GIS
Software for Building a Spatial Data Infrastructure. In: E. Bocher and M. Neteler (eds), Geospatial Free and Open Source Software in the 21st Century: Proceedings of the first Open Source Geospatial Research
Symposium. Heidelberg: Springer.

ESRI 2010 - GIS Best Practices: Spatial Data Infrastructure. http://www.gdmc.nl/publications/2001/Spatial_data_infrasructure.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer above, sometimes financial resources are also counted among the components of an SDI.
See for instance Loenen, B. van; (2006) Developing geographic information infrastructures.
Avaialble from: http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/13658810701851412